# Jtable need help loading columns from text file [JAVA]

Tags: java, file, text, jtable

I am trying to get the following text file to come up into this 'Jtable'.. I’m having a hard time getting all the data/columns to appear.. I know that it’s something easy I’m just new to java so any help would be appreciated.

My text file:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6
1b;2b;3b;4b;5b;6b
1C;2C;3C;4C;5C;6C
```

My code so far:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JtableTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new JtableTest ().createUI();
        }
    };

    EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
}

private void createUI() {

    try {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTable table = new JTable();

        String readLine = null;

     //   DatabaseTableModel tableModel = new DatabaseTableModel();
        File file = new File ("JtableTest.txt");

        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(reader);//Need to close this

        List<Dentry> studentList = new ArrayList<Dentry>();
        while ((readLine = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitData = readLine.split(";");

            Dentry dentry = new Dentry();
            dentry.setName(splitData[0]);
            dentry.setNumbers(Arrays.copyOfRange(splitData, 1, splitData.length));
            studentList.add(dentry);
        }

        DatabaseTableModel tableModel = new DatabaseTableModel();
        tableModel.setList(studentList);////////////
        table.setModel(tableModel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setTitle("File to JTable");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    } catch(IOException ex) {}
}

class Dentry {

    private String name;
    private String[] number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber(int index) {
        String value = null;
        if (index >= 0 && index < number.length) {
            value = number[index];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setNumbers(String... number) {
        this.number = number;

class DatabaseTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Dentry> list = new ArrayList<Dentry>();
    private String[] columnNames = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

    public void setList(List<Dentry> list) {
        this.list = list;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return list.get(rowIndex).getName();

            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:                 
                return list.get(rowIndex).getNumber(columnIndex);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You data is split over 6 columns but your pojo only allows for 2

Comment: Yeah I know I was wondering how to change that as it will never display right no matter what I try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data contains 6 columns, but your pojo only allows for 2 (the name and a number).

Start by changing your pojo to support multiple columns

```
class Dentry {

    private String name;
    private String[] number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber(int index) {
        String value = null;
        if (index >= 0 && index < number.length) {
            value = number[index];
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setNumbers(String... number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

All I've done here is allowed your to apply a variable length of numbers and provided a convenience method to access them.

Next, you need to change the way you're loading the data so you can supply all the other elements from the line in the file to your pojo

```
        List<Dentry> studentList = new ArrayList<Dentry>();
        while ((readLine = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitData = readLine.split(";");

            Dentry dentry = new Dentry();
            dentry.setName(splitData[0]);
            dentry.setNumbers(Arrays.copyOfRange(splitData, 1, splitData.length));
            studentList.add(dentry);
        }
```

This just creates a copy of the `splitData` from the second element (index `1`) to the last element inclusive.

I also changed the `getVaueAt` method to make it simpler to get the number for the specified column...

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return list.get(rowIndex).getName();

        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            return list.get(rowIndex).getNumber(columnIndex - 1);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

You could just use `default` as the pojo checks the range of the index, but this is a nice demonstration of the fall through nature of a `switch` statement.

[image: Table of numbers]

Comment: Thanks mad programmer, I did try your code but I'm having trouble at line 57:
    DatabaseTableModel tableModel = new DatabaseTableModel();

Comment: Which ones line 57? Cause it run fine for me

Comment: Your update code is missing the closing brace (`}`) for the `setNumbers` method and `Dentry` class

Comment: Thanks MadProgramer! I got it to work after I sent that.. It's missing the two column as shown on your picture

Comment: That's how your data and parsing works out.  If you were to ignore the "name", then it would probably fill out more correctly and you should probably change `return list.get(rowIndex).getNumber(columnIndex)` to `return list.get(rowIndex).getNumber(columnIndex - 1)` :P